# Jquery UI autocomplete show all data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm using the autocomplete widget of JQuery using JSON to parsed but doesn't work, displays all json data.

please help me

This is my script:

```
$(function() {    
    $( "#test2" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://some_link/folder/file.json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {terms: request.term},
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.city+' ('+item.country_name+'), '+item.currency,
                            value: item.city
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,


    });
});
```

this is json

```
[{"country_name":"DENMARK","city":"Aalborg","currency":"EUR"},{"country_name":"DENMARK","city":"Aarhus","currency":"EUR"}]
```

this is html

```
<div class="form-box">
    <center><label style="color:white;">City <small>*</small></label></center>
    <input type="text" class="text" id="test2" placeholder="Your City">
  </div><!-- End Box -->
```

Please help !

TNX

Comment: Try this : $.parseJSON(data). If this does not work try doing json stringify first and then do parse json.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not applying a filter to the requested json file. You're getting the whole file. I'm currently assuming that the json file you mention is a plain json file (meaning, it has no server-side code who create it).

You can do two things: a) modify your return function inside the `$.map` so you can remove all those values who does not fulfill your filter (i.e., you can remove the cities who doesn't contain part of the text given). In order to find what values meet your criteria, you can use something as simple as [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

Or b) you can create the JSOn server-side using some server language such as PHP, Java, C# and so on, and there, you can read the `terms` parameter you passed on `data` at the `$.ajax` there and perform the filtering via server-side. Then, you just need to return the values who actually meet your criteria.